# Text File to JavaScript Nested Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this .txt file to change to a nested array:

```
000011000000
000100001100
000001100001
010010001000
100101000100
101010010001
001000001001
000001000111
010100100010
010010010010
000000011100
001001110000
```

to the format:

```
var data = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ]
```

what I have done so far is:

1. Read the file:

```
function readMatrixFile(){
    var inputElement = document.getElementById("adjencyMatrixInput");
    var fileList = inputElement.files;
    var plainMatrix = new FileReader();
    plainMatrix.readAsText(fileList[0]);
    plainMatrix.onload = function () {
        //Add to Matrix
        renderMatrix(plainMatrix)
    }
}
```

and
2. Split the File

```
function renderMatrix(plainMatrix) {
    var matrix = plainMatrix.result;
    var mtx = [];

    matrix = matrix.split("\n");
    
}
```

I know I need to push through a for loop, but not sure how to get the nested array.

Answer (score 4):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by a newline, then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each item and convert the string into an array of characters with [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const str = `000011000000
000100001100
000001100001
010010001000
100101000100
101010010001
001000001001
000001000111
010100100010
010010010010
000000011100
001001110000`

const res = str.split("\n").map(e => [...e])
console.log(res)
```

To convert the characters to numbers, map over the array of characters and parse each item:

```js
const str = `000011000000
000100001100
000001100001
010010001000
100101000100
101010010001
001000001001
000001000111
010100100010
010010010010
000000011100
001001110000`

const res = str.split("\n").map(e => [...e].map(e => +e))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is close, but the result needed is not a nested array of characters, it's a nesterd array of numbers.

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Just on error it does is that it adds an additional element to each array except the last.

Comment: `0: (13) [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1: (13) [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
2: (13) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
3: (13) [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4: (13) [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
5: (13) [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
6: (13) [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
7: (13) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
8: (13) [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
9: (13) [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
10: (13) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
11: (12) [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Comment: @ELMERRONIERHUITZ Are you sure your input data is correct? Can't reproduce that behavior with the code in my answer.

Comment: confirming data is the same as in original mention

Comment: @ELMERRONIERHUITZ Try running the code snippet in my answer. The number of items in each array is the same as the length of the line.

Comment: @spectric it seems the file has an /r as well. I had already removed the /n

Answer (score 0):

You turn `matrix` into a a string of ones and zeros, you just need to split the string and convert them to numbers

```js
function renderMatrix(plainMatrix) {
    var matrix = plainMatrix.result;

    var mtx = matrix.split("\n"); // mtx is now an array of strings of ones and zeros
    
    mtx = mtx.map(string => string.split('')); // mtx is now an array of arrays of number string

    mtx = mtx.map(nested => nested.map(numberString => Number(numberString))); // mtx is now what you want

}
```

Comment: This is a good solution but it also gives an additional element in the first 11 arrays.